# Circular dependencies with node modules import using Browserify and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browserify, cjsx

I just figured out that I have circular dependencies in my modules. *(`cjsx` stands for Coffee+JSX)*

I have a file `index.cjsx`which contains the following:

```
modules =
    App: require('./App')
    Code: require('../../components/elements/code/Code')
    Icon: require('./icon/Icon')
    Page: require('./page/Page')
    Toolbar: require('./toolbar/Toolbar')
    Toolbars: require('./toolbar/Toolbars')
    Wysiwyg: require('./wysiwyg/Wysiwyg')

console.log modules
module.exports = modules
```

Then, on my application, I use the following syntax:

```
{ Icon, Toolbar, Toolbars } = require '../index'
```

The `index.cjsx` is here just to allow this syntax and avoid to require each module separately.

But now I'm facing the issue where my `App` component requires the `index` file, and my `index` file requires `App`. There is a circular dependency. It's not causing a bug by itself but things get complicated at some point because now, when I require `index` in some component, I only get an empty object `{}`.

When I add logs in `Wysiwyg`, I see the following:

```
script.js:197 Object {}// The object is empty, console.log require '../index' (in Wysiwyg)
script.js:90 Object {App: Object}// The object is not empty here and contains everything I need. (console.log modules, in index.cjsx)
script.js:209 undefined undefined
script.js:45151 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Wysiwyg`.
```

It looks like my index is actually loaded after it has been required.
I wonder if I can do something to fix this or if I must require each package separately from the component itself. Thanks for input :)

---

I fixed the issue by not requiring index from the App component (which is the master and is at the root directory. And by not listing the App component in the index file.

Answer (score 0):

you should use index.js file to require only the files in the current folder. this way you avoid circular dependencies if you manage your folders right. In your example, you would add an index.cjsx in the folder toolbar for example with just `Toolbar` and `Toolbars` and then to

```
{ Toolbar, Toolbars } = require './toolbar'
```

Note: you can omit the index file, it is assumed if you put a folder path

Comment: I fixed the issue by not requiring `index` from the `App` component (which is the master and is at the root directory. And by not listing the `App` component in the `index` file. I'll try it that way.